# How to stop slide-out bar from hiding when we click on any list on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dashboard with **slideout** sidebar. When I press toggle it comes out. But When I click on any list (tab) on sidebar it again hide. I want to hide only through toggle. 
My code is working fine but I have to add functionality(**stop slide-out bar from hiding when we click on any list on it**). 
When I press toggle it open like following.

[image]

But when I click on any tab on **slidout** sidebar(Ex Home) it again hide, It should be only hide by toggle. 
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Making it swipeable - Swipeable Side Menu</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
      body, html {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          overflow:hidden;
          font-family: helvetica;
          font-weight: 100;
      }
      .container {
          position: relative;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          left: 0;
          -webkit-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -ms-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      }
      .container.open-sidebar {
          left: 240px;
      }

      .swipe-area {
          position: absolute;
          width: 50px;
          left: 0;
      top: 0;
          height: 100%;
          background: #f3f3f3;
          z-index: 0;
      }
      #sidebar {
          background: #DF314D;
          position: absolute;
          width: 240px;
          height: 100%;
          left: -240px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      #sidebar ul {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          list-style: none;
      }
      #sidebar ul li {
          margin: 0;
      }
      #sidebar ul li a {
          padding: 15px 20px;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 100;
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #C9223D;
          -webkit-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -ms-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }
      #sidebar ul li:hover a {
          background: #C9223D;
      }
      .main-content {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          padding: 10px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          position: relative;
      }
      .main-content .content{
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      padding-left: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      }
      .main-content .content h1{
          font-weight: 100;
      }
      .main-content .content p{
          width: 100%;
          line-height: 160%;
      }
      .main-content #sidebar-toggle {
          background: #DF314D;
          border-radius: 3px;
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          padding: 10px 7px;
          float: left;
      }
      .main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar{
           display: block;
          width: 18px;
          margin-bottom: 3px;
          height: 2px;
          background-color: #fff;
          border-radius: 1px;   
      }
      .main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar:last-child{
           margin-bottom: 0;   
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function(){
        $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
          var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
          $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
          if($(toggle_el).hasClass("open-sidebar")){
              console.log($('.content').width()); 
              console.log(parseInt($('.content').width())-240);
              $('.content').width(parseInt($('.content').width())-240);
          }
          else
            $(".content").css('width','100%');
        });
         $(".swipe-area").swipe({
              swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
                  {
                      if (phase=="move" && direction =="right") {
                           $(".container").addClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                      if (phase=="move" && direction =="left") {
                           $(".container").removeClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                  }
          }); 
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sidebar">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="demo3.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="demo3.html">Explore</a></li>
              <li><a href="demo3.html">Users</a></li>
              <li><a href="demo3.html">Sign Out</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="main-content">
          <div class="swipe-area"></div>
          <a href="#" data-toggle=".container" id="sidebar-toggle">
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="content">
              <h1>Creating Swipeable Side Menu For the Web</h1>
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: Provide only code needed not all of yours.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwWRYV

Comment: the only thing I did was replacing the `$(window).load` for `$(window).ready` and the `a href="demo3.html"` for `a href="#"` and it works.

Comment: Side-note: There is not need for `parseInt($('.content').width())` as `$('.content').width()` returns a number (no "px" suffix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, but the reason that clicking your tabs "appear" to toggle the menu in again, is that you are are simply *loading new pages*. The whole page starts again from scratch, *with the menu closed* as HTML requests are stateless and it does not know about the open menu *on the previous page*.

Some options to work around this are: record the open state of the panel (e.g. using a cookie, or URL parameter) and check that value on each page load, or just load the appropriate parts of the pages using Ajax (preferred).

Using the Ajax solution turns it into an SPA (Single Page Application) e.g the Javascript running in the page is never lost.

The following example will add a handler for the menu link. It takes the `href` from the clicked link and uses it to `$.get()` the new page. It then extracts the `.content` part of the page (I am assuming your pages all follow the same pattern) then replaces the existing page content div with it.

```
 $('#sidebar a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     // Load the target URL using Ajax
     var href = $(this).attr("href");
     $.get(href, function(html){
         // Extract the content portion of the loaded page
         var content = $(html).find('.content');
         $('.content').replace(content);
     });
 });
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/f51k7eev/3/

**Notes:**

- I also changed your load handler to use a DOM ready handler, as that is the best way for jQuery (it runs as soon as the DOM is ready and not wait for images to load etc).
- I removed a couple of `parseInt` calls as jQuery's `.width()` returns a number of pixels (without the "px" suffix).

**Issues:** If you start down the SPA path, you will need to update the browser address bar url manually (e.g. using history.js), otherwise a page refresh will always take you back to the first page.

Answer (score 0):

I have replace href="javascript:void" instead of href="your page link"

```js
 $(window).load(function() {
   $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
     var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
     $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
     if ($(toggle_el).hasClass("open-sidebar")) {
       console.log($('.content').width());
       console.log(parseInt($('.content').width()) - 240);
       $('.content').width(parseInt($('.content').width()) - 240);
     } else
       $(".content").css('width', '100%');
   });
   $(".swipe-area").swipe({
     swipeStatus: function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers) {
       if (phase == "move" && direction == "right") {
         $(".container").addClass("open-sidebar");
         return false;
       }
       if (phase == "move" && direction == "left") {
         $(".container").removeClass("open-sidebar");
         return false;
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
 body, html {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          overflow:hidden;
          font-family: helvetica;
          font-weight: 100;
      }
      .container {
          position: relative;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          left: 0;
          -webkit-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -ms-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      }
      .container.open-sidebar {
          left: 240px;
      }

      .swipe-area {
          position: absolute;
          width: 50px;
          left: 0;
      top: 0;
          height: 100%;
          background: #f3f3f3;
          z-index: 0;
      }
      #sidebar {
          background: #DF314D;
          position: absolute;
          width: 240px;
          height: 100%;
          left: -240px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      #sidebar ul {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          list-style: none;
      }
      #sidebar ul li {
          margin: 0;
      }
      #sidebar ul li a {
          padding: 15px 20px;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 100;
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #C9223D;
          -webkit-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -ms-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }
      #sidebar ul li:hover a {
          background: #C9223D;
      }
      .main-content {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          padding: 10px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          position: relative;
      }
      .main-content .content{
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      padding-left: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      }
      .main-content .content h1{
          font-weight: 100;
      }
      .main-content .content p{
          width: 100%;
          line-height: 160%;
      }
      .main-content #sidebar-toggle {
          background: #DF314D;
          border-radius: 3px;
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          padding: 10px 7px;
          float: left;
      }
      .main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar{
           display: block;
          width: 18px;
          margin-bottom: 3px;
          height: 2px;
          background-color: #fff;
          border-radius: 1px;   
      }
      .main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar:last-child{
           margin-bottom: 0;   
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Explore</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Users</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Sign Out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="swipe-area"></div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle=".container" id="sidebar-toggle">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Creating Swipeable Side Menu For the Web</h1>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't want to remove the link, because without link it will be purpose less. Please check it..

Comment: my question is "How to stop slide-out bar from hiding when we click on any list on it?"  my code is working fine but add this functionality...

Comment: @neelabhsingh means when you click on Home Link and side-out bar does not hide. am i right?

Comment: When I click on Home Link and side-out bar should not hide.

Comment: How to stop slide-out bar from hiding when we click on any list on it?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to your code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function(e){
        $("[data-toggle]").click(function(e) {
           e.stopPropagation();
           //your code 
        )};
      )};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer But There is no effect. It again go inside when I press any tab..